# Index of Absolute Maximum Value of A Coefficient Matrix Contained in An Augmented Matrix

Tags: matlab

How can I find index of absolute maximum value of a coefficient matrix contained in an augmented matrix? for example, consider:

```
A = 
    1     -2     1     5
   -3      2    -3     10
    2     -5     5     15
```

MATLAB code should return:

```
row = 3
col = 2
```

**Note 1:** If there exist more than one element with absolute maximum value in the coefficient matrix, the code should return one of them.
**Note 2:** I **do not** want save coefficient matrix in a new variable or in the same augmented matrix. like the following solution

```
B = A(:, 1:3);
[~, Index] = max(abs(B(:)));
[row, col] = ind2sub(size(B), Index)
```

or

```
A = A(:, 1:3);
[~, Index] = max(abs(A(:)));
[row, col] = ind2sub(size(A), Index)
```

**Note 3:** My solution is

```
var = max(max(abs(A(:, 1:3))));
[row, col] = find(abs(A(:, 1:3)) == var, 1)
```

but I am looking for an easier way.

Comment: Why don't you like the first situation? Do you really have memory limitations or are you arbitrarily trying to reduce the number of lines of code? But if you really really want to, then you can use `reshape(A(:,1:3),[],1)` in place of `A(:)`.

Answer (score 1):

my solution is as follows:

```
[~,col] = max(max(abs(A(:,1:3))))
[~,row] = max(abs(A(:,col)))
```

Firstly, through two max function could find the col index of maximum element. Based on this,

the second task is just to find the row index of the maximum element in the corresponding col.

I hope it can help you.